# Array vs Matrix in terms of memory in Java

Tags: java, c, arrays, matrix

I am working on a project that involves heuristics, and I built it in Java (Should have probably made it in C).
I am running into problems with memory.

My tree is built up with object nodes, and each object contains an array, a matrix, and three integers.
I already cut down many other values, in order to try and save more memory space, however, it still isn't enough.

So, I was thinking that I could also cut down the matrix, and transform it into an array.
However, my whole project is built on coordinates, to reach a certain point in the matrix.
So before I make any change, I would like to know how much (or not so much) this would affect memory usage.

Edit: The array and matrix both are made of int primitives.

The array is array[25] and the matrix is matrix[5][5].

The matrix represents the board of the game, with information of whether the field is empty, or has a certain type of piece inside it (all int).

I am talking about 16GB of RAM usage, and 25 million nodes.

I made this method, to clone arrays:

```
public int[] cloneArray(int[] array){
    int i = 0;
    int[] clone = new int[array.length];
    while (i < array.length){
        clone[i] = array[i];
        i++;
    }
    return clone;
}
```

Similar methods were made, to clone matrixes, and the objects themselves.

Edit:
After finding out about the existence of a profiler, I made a check.
Here is a screenshot of the results:
[image: Java profiler stats]

I think these numbers make sense, because in the console, you can see nearly as many nodes that were counted, as you can see in the profiler, the states (in the console, "estados" is the pointer of the state that is currently being expanded).

So, in the profiler, we can see almost 20m states, which are the generated nodes.
Each state contains 1 array and 1 matrix.

We can see 138m arrays, which divided by 6 equals 23m.
And since a matrix is 5x5, then 5x23m of the arrays are contained in the matrix, and the other 23m are the arrays.

Am I making sense? Is this interpretation accurate?

Here is a dropbox link, so you can check the full resolution image:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7wxz8vch1wnrsyr/Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: "Matrix" as in two-dimensional array or a custom object?

Comment: Yes, two dimensional array.

Comment: Do the array and the matrix contain `int` primitives or `Integer` objects?  And how much memory are we talking about here?

Comment: they contain int primitives. We are talking about 16GB of RAM, by building up 25 milion nodes.

Comment: Habe you tried increasing the memory limits of the JVM? The defaults are not rather small for large scale applications.

Comment: Yes, I increased it to use up all the RAM. If I increase it beyond the RAM capacity, and enter into paging files, the whole system lags.

Comment: An array blocks all memory allocated for it, so when you are creating a two-dimensional array the whole space is occupied - and if you have a sparsely populated array, this blocks more memory than necessary, yes.

Comment: "Should have probably made it in C" - If you had also tagged your question with `c` while saying this your question would have probably already received several upvotes :)

Comment: "An array blocks all memory allocated for it". Yes, but we are talking about either 5 arrays of length 5, that are inside an array of length 5, or 1 array of length 25. And what you mean by a sparsely populated array?

Comment: If you have so many nodes I guess that using a 1D array instead of a 2D might make a difference to the expense of course that it's error-prone to get the indices correctly. On the other hand if you are so tight in RAM you might easily be in trouble again

Comment: @WilhelmSorban http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix and yes, a two-dimensional array has an additional overhead compared to a one-dimensional array as a two-dimensional array is actually an array of arrays so for every row you have the common "array overhead".

Comment: By my calculations, 25 million nodes, the way you've described them, should take up 6GB.  There must be something else going on here.  Changing the 2D array to a 1D array should bring the total down to 5.5GB, which isn't really significantly different, compared to the 10GB that is unaccounted for.

Comment: Can you please share the way you made that calculation?

Comment: And what I experience is this: On each node that is generated, and added the the arraylist of objects, I have an incrementing number, that is printed on the screen. If I give less memory to the JVM, it starts pausing to generate nodes, then it generates more, and then pauses, each time more often, until the pause takes forever.

Comment: So with more memory, these pauses start to occur later in time, since the beginning of the run command.

Comment: The 1D array should take 104 bytes - that's 4 bytes per entry plus 4 bytes for the array reference itself.  The 2D array should take 124 bytes - thats 4 bytes per entry, 4 bytes for each of the five 1D arrays inside, plus 4 bytes for the array reference itself.  Then, you've got an additional three 4-byte integers.  So the total memory per node should be 104 + 124 + 12 = 240 bytes.  Then 240 x 25 million = 6 billion.

Comment: I added a method, which I use to clone arrays/matrixes/objects. By my understandings, the memory allocation should be dereferenced, every time the method returns. Can't really think of anything else...

Comment: I think you mean deallocated, not dereferenced.  I would suggest running a profiler against your code.

Comment: Yes, deallocated. Never heard of Java profiler, I will look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of examples:

```
int[] array = new int[25];

int[][] matrix = new int[5][5];
```

The space occupied by the array is:

- 25 x 4 byte ints (the array contents)
- 12 bytes of object header for the array
- total 112 bytes

A 2D `int` matrix in Java is actually an array of arrays, so the space occupied by the matrix is

- (5 x 4 byte ints + 12 bytes of array header) x 5.
- 5 x 4 byte references + 12 bytes of array header
- total 192 bytes

(The above assumes a 32 bit JVM, and *typical* array header sizes.  Those are platform specific assumptions, but for any JVM platform you should be able to tie them down with specificity.  And for Oracle HotSpot / OpenJDK JVMs since Java 6, the source code is available for anyone to see.)

Note of course that as the arrays / matrices get larger, the relative saving for an `int[N^2]` versus an `int[N][N]` becomes smaller.

Comment: Quick question, Stephen.  Why are there 12 bytes for an array header?  You can see that my calculation in the comments was slightly different - I had 4 bytes for an array header.  What is in the header other than a single address?

Comment: @DavidWallace See [this answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/162568/73603). Essentially, one word for the array's class reference, one for synchronization and garbage collection flags, one for the size.

Comment: Thanks @PatriciaShanahan that all makes sense.  Also, interesting that this is 20 or 24 bytes on a 64 bit JVM.  This really does start to all add up.

Comment: It seems to me that on a 64 bit JVM, this could easily be 124 bytes for the 1D array and 284 bytes for the 2D array; making 420 bytes in total per node, making 10.5GB for 25 million nodes.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the profiler stats, and some details. Can you please check if it's accurate?

Answer (score 1):

Your question may suggest hidden problem in your code rather then "out of memory problem". the heap memory is not finish so fast , you need your code to be extremely heavy in order to get there.

still, I'll dare to say that changing 2 dimensional matrix into an array wouldn't change the memory usage much.
speaking on which - the 2 most common ways to implement higher-dimensions arrays (2 and above) are 1) slice it to one dimension array, then use the formula :

```
arr[a][b].. = arr[a+b+..]
```

2) use pointers to pointers , then you get an array of pointers , which points to another array of pointers and so on until the final level which are real objects

this said , (again , with dare) , Java may already slice the matrix into one dimension array behind the scenes.

any way , I highly suspect you have memory leak in your code , or not-ending-recursion, or a combination of the above . try to see you're not there before trying to implement what you suggested.

Comment: I doubt I have a memory leak, because as I deleted an other array and a matrix, from the constructor, the nodes that can be generated almost doubled.

Comment: *"since Java is a managed-code language, and Oracle JVM code is not an open one , we can't answer 100% on how java run memory , or what sort of optimizations it does on the code ."*  This is rubbish.  The source code of the core JVM and the GCs are all open source.  AFAIK, the only source code that you can't get is for the "special stuff" that you need a paid license to enable.